# String pattern, match the first, outermost pair of brackets?

Tags: string, lua, brackets, lua-patterns

So here's a trivial example, say I have an equation like

```
local equation = "((5*2)+3)-(3^5)"
```

And I want to capture `"((5*2)+3)"`

At first I tried

```
equation:match("%((.*)%)")
```

But `*` is greedy, so it captured the whole equation.

Then I tried

```
equation:match("%((.-)%)")
```

But `-` is lazy, and it captured `"((5*2)"`

Obviously I'm going about this wrong. How should I capture the brackets with a string pattern?

Comment: I'd like to avoid manually parsing if at all possible

Comment: `equation:match'%b()'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is `%b` pattern, which matches balanced strings. In this example, you can use `%b()` to match a string that starts with `(`, and ends with the corresponding `)`:

```
equation:match("%b()")
```